# Using OAuth connection type to Access Salesforce via Talend Data Integration

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce, talend

I am trying to access Salesforce data using Talend Data Integration Tool.I tried establishing connection using OAuth, However there is some issue with **Callback Port**.

Is there anyone who also went through this kind of issue? If yes then what port number did you used.